# Sequelize could not create a new table

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm currently learning sequelize and its define method is used to create new database table, but it is not working...there is no error...do you know whats going on?

```js
var express = require('express');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = require('../db/sequelize_conf.js');
var router = express.Router();

var User = sequelize.define('user', 
{
    name: Sequelize.STRING,
    password: Sequelize.STRING,
    mail: Sequelize.STRING
},
{ 
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: false
});

User.create({
    name: 'XiaoMing',
    password: '1234567890',
    mail: 'xiaoming@qq.com'
}).then(function(result){
    console.log('inserted XiaoMing ok');
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log('inserted XiaoMing error');
    console.log(err.message);
});

module.exports=router;
```

It says the user table doesnt exist....

Comment: I'm a bit confused by you saying "there is no error" and "it says the user table doesn't exist". Which of those two is it, and what is the rest of your tracelog?

Answer (score 1):

Okay ,

First check in the database if user table is there or not , coz the below code won't create a new table , it will **just create a new entry in to user table**

```
User.create({
    name: 'XiaoMing',
    password: '1234567890',
    mail: 'xiaoming@qq.com'
})
```

---

If you **want to create a table then** you can use ,

```
// This will create only all the tables defines via sequelize
sequelize.sync().then(() => 
    // put your user create code inside this
);

// OR

// This will create only user table
User.sync().then(() => {
    // put your user create code inside this
});
```

I hope this will clear all your doubts